# Copy files in a date range while preserving folder structure

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I need to copy from a huge archive a subset of the files that were modified in a given date range.
I also need to preserve the directory structure.

Example of powershell code that may work:

```
#Delete dest
Remove-Item $destPath\* -Recurse -Force
#copying file from srcPath to destPath
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcPath | Copy-Item -Destination $destPath -Recurse -Container
#deleting files according to date
Get-ChildItem -Path $destPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.lastWriteTime -lt ($Curr_date).adddays($Max_days) -or $_.LastWriteTime -gt ($Curr_date).adddays($Min_days) } | Remove-Item -Force
Write-Host "Done"
```

The problem with the above is that I am needlessly copying files. Imagine that I have a huge archive of files, it will be prohibitively costly to copy them all.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I'd use robocopy /mir /minage n /maxage n

Answer (score 1):

I am using this command in the end

```
Robocopy $srcPath $destPath *.* /MAXAGE:$Max_days /MINAGE:$Min_days /S
```